# could not broadcast input array from shape (250,500,3) into shape (0,238,3)

Tags: python, numpy

This is the code that I have found to paste one image to another
https://gist.github.com/uchidama/41d1c0a068f1d36dec2706715a7f17aa

Need to modify it to have an image:

```
img = cv2.imread("../Data/cropped_images/6.png")

width,height = (768 , 1024)

blank_image = cv2.imread("../Data/LabeledData/Annotation/A_0030001930.jpg")

print(blank_image.shape)
print(img.shape)
x_offset = int((width - img.shape[1])/2)
y_offset = int((height - img.shape[0])/2)
print(x_offset)
print(y_offset)
print(img.shape[0])
print(img.shape[1])
blank_image[ y_offset:y_offset+img.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+img.shape[1]] = img

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(blank_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-172-1620eee28625> in <module>
     12 print(img.shape[0])
     13 print(img.shape[1])
---> 14 blank_image[ y_offset:y_offset+img.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+img.shape[1]] = img
     15 
     16 plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(blank_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (250,500,3) into shape (0,366,3)
```

I am unsure of how to solve this.

Edit:

These are the shapes that I got

```
(250, 500, 3)
(250, 500, 3)
134
387
250
500
```

Comment: Could you post whole output? - you print a lot of information useful for debugging there :)

Comment: possiby ann issue with the layers. Each of your images has 3 layers you dont seem to be taking that into account